# How to use GeoLite database in MapReduce hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to code a Map Reduce program, in which I am trying to use a GeoLite database to resolve the location of the IP addresses. I am not sure how to pass the database file to the mapper and also what dependencies are to be used?

Comment: Too broad question. As far as I know, GeoLite is also provided in CSV format, which could be imported in Hadoop using Hive. Could you please concretize your question?

Comment: I don't want to use the CSV file, I want to use the database file. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of using the GeoLite database in Map Reduce hadoop is by passing the database as cached file, by doing using:

> DistributedCache.addCacheFile(inputPath.toUri(),
>   job.getConfiguration());

You can pass the .mmdb file to each mapper using the cache file.

The dependencies I used for using the GeoLite Database are:

```
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.db</groupId>
            <artifactId>maxmind-db</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

You can then override the setup and pass the cache file to the mapper like this:

```
@Override
public void setup(Context context)

{
  Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

try {

  cachefiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);

  File database = new File(cachefiles[0].toString()); 

  reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Which then I used in the map function like this:

```
public void map(Object key, Text line, Context context) throws IOException,
      InterruptedException {

    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address.getHostAddress());
    CityResponse response = null;
    try {
      response = reader.city(ipAddress);
    } catch (GeoIp2Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    Country country = response.getCountry();
    String count = country.getName(); // 'US'

    if (country.getName() == null) {
      return;
    }
```

You can view a working example [here](https://github.com/Rachitahuja20/Hadoop-learning/tree/master/MapReduceGeoLocation).